# Initialize Nested Dictionaries in c#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, visual-studio-2017, list-initialization

I need to know how to access and initialize a series of Dictionaries containing other dictionaries.
For example, if I have

```
class Conv{
    Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<double>>>> valori;
}
```

And I want to initiate the parameter "valori" with random numbers, how can I do it?
I would do it like

```
valori[n1].Values[n2].Values[n3]
```

But after the first "Value", MVS gives me an error. Maybe I have to allocate the memory first? I learned a little bit of c++, but I'm still new to c#
Also let me know if I forgot something important in my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create the sub-dictionaries for each key before using them

```
var list = new List<double> {d};
var d1 = new Dictionary<int, List<double>> {{n3, list }};
var d2 = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<double>>> {{n2, d1}};
valori[n1] = d2;
```

You can also write this short in one line:

```
valori[n1] = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<double>>> {{n2, new Dictionary<int, List<double>> {{n3, new List<double> {d}}}}};
```

When all dictionaries are actually created you can access them normally:

```
 var savedList = valori[n1][n2][n3];
```

Since this syntax is very clunky and it is easy to make a mistake (missing if a sub-dictionary exists, overriding data, etc), I'd strongly suggest changing the datastructure or at least hiding it in a dedicated class

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i'm mistaken but I can't think of situation that you would need this kind of structure but nevertheless here's my help:

First of all you need to assign the variable or you will get the error :
"Use of unassign local variable".So the code will be like:

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<double>>>> valori=new 
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<double>>>>();
```

Secondly you need to add some data to the dictionary in order to use it later so
you should do :

```
valori.Add(2, new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<double>>>());
valori.Add(3, new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<double>>>());
valori.Add(4, new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<double>>>());
```

"notice that keys are different"

And instead of `new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<double>>>()` you should 
enter a value of that type.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just so you know, I have to deserialize a Json file that's like a list of frame<persona<joints<x, y, z>>>. Then, I want to pass its value in a class that's persona<frame<joints<x, y, z>>>